# NoClassDefFoundError on Kindle Fire

Tags: java, android

I have an application that I developed for Android. My application's build SDK is API level 17 and minimum SDK is level 7. The application runs perfectly on all Android devices I've tested on. However, when I run it on my Kindle Fire HD, I get a NoClassFoundError before the main activity can even show. The class in question is a helper class used in the Main Activity. This loads perfectly on other devices.

I should also mention that no Google services are being used by the Main Activity or the class in question, so the Kindle shouldn't be having trouble with it. Can anyone shed some light on this issue?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the LogCat output:

```
07-23 09:43:24.418: E/Crittercism(4993): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.s1.activity.HomeActivity
07-23 09:43:24.418: E/Crittercism(4993):    at com.s1.activity.S1TabActivity.createTabs(S1TabActivity.java:337)
07-23 09:43:24.418: E/Crittercism(4993):    at com.s1.activity.S1TabActivity.onCreate(S1TabActivity.java:100)
07-23 09:43:24.418: E/Crittercism(4993):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4635)
07-23 09:43:24.418: E/Crittercism(4993):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
07-23 09:43:24.418: E/Crittercism(4993):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2031)
07-23 09:43:24.418: E/Crittercism(4993):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2092)
07-23 09:43:24.418: E/Crittercism(4993):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:126)
07-23 09:43:24.418: E/Crittercism(4993):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1172)
07-23 09:43:24.418: E/Crittercism(4993):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-23 09:43:24.418: E/Crittercism(4993):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-23 09:43:24.418: E/Crittercism(4993):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4586)
07-23 09:43:24.418: E/Crittercism(4993):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-23 09:43:24.418: E/Crittercism(4993):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-23 09:43:24.418: E/Crittercism(4993):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
07-23 09:43:24.418: E/Crittercism(4993):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
07-23 09:43:24.418: E/Crittercism(4993):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: You should inspect the log cat output and/or paste relevant parts here :)

Comment: error log will tell you what class is missing.

Comment: The class is not actually missing. It is there! But its not being found. @robotoaster

Comment: without class itself it is difficult to say. I assume manifest is ok as you have pointed that it works on vanilla devices.

Answer (score 0):

I also found that error when I updated my ADT plugin. Have you updated it recently?

I solved it like this:

Right click on your project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Order and Export

Check Android Private Libraries.

This worked for me, I hope it works for you too :)